# How to add alias name for my task in symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a question - how to add my own task alias in Symfony 1.4?

For example, there is a 'cc' alias for 'cache:clear' command. I want to make an alias of my command 'SuperLongCommandNameForSymfonyTask'... but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/task/cache/sfCacheClearTask.class.php#L35

you only have to add this line :

```
$this->aliases = array('cc');
```